# google-cloud-storage CORS for request headers

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I can't figure out how to allow request headers in Google Cloud Storage CORS requests.

According to the documentation, [the Range HTTP header is supported](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#range), but I can't find a way to allow that for client-side XMLHttpRequests.

Here's my CORS configuration:

```
$ gsutil cors get gs://df-ai-movies
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Date"]}]
```

[Example page](https://benlubar.github.io/cmvjs/#https://df-ai-movies.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `responseHeader` key is used for both response *and* request headers.

My new config looks like this:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Date", "Range"]}]
```